# How can I make upload status div disappear after the item was successfully uploaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building an uploading experience base on [Dmuploader](https://plugins.jquery.com/dmuploader/) with a div showing all the file uploading status. Here is the code for the main div "uploader", and div "file" for each file which is uploading.

```html
<div id="uploader">

    <div class="file" id="9414af9ec02b">
        <div class="info">
            <span class="filename" title="ABC.jpg [Size: 7.6 MiB - type: image/jpeg]">#1 - ABC.jpg</span>
            <small>Status: <span class="status uploading success">Upload Complete</span></small>
        </div>
        <div class="bar">
            <div class="progress uploading success" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End 1st file upload status -->
    
    <div class="file" id="6ca2ffc3b9f1">
        <div class="info">
            <span class="filename" title="happy-new-year.jpg [Size: 274.2 KiB - type: image/jpeg]">#2 - happy-new-year.jpg</span>
            <small>Status: <span class="status uploading success">Upload Complete</span></small>
        </div>
        <div class="bar">
            <div class="progress uploading success" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End 2nd file upload status -->

...
    
</div><!-- End Uploader -->
```

What I need now is to make each **file div** automatically disappear after the file is successfully uploaded, otherwise the **uploader div** will be longer and longer with trash information.

Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing your code, I think you would be interested in this possibly: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/

Comment: i assume you skipped reading the documentation -- use the (onUploadSuccess) function -- https://github.com/danielm/uploader

Answer (score 0):

As Tasos pointed out, there is a function built-in to the plugin to help with this. One way would be:

```
onUploadSuccess: function(id, data){
  $('#' + id).hide();
}
```

This uses jQuery to select the element and then hide it, in case you wanted it later it still exists.

Or simply remove it with plain javascript:

```
onUploadSuccess: function(id, data){
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

should do the trick, though I haven't tested it.